# Can't see Soft Credit fields on a Contribution Detail Report?

Tags: civireport, soft-credit

When I add Soft Credit columns to a Contribution Detail Report, the data doesn't show - they're just empty cells:
[image]

Comment: Do you have soft credits for those contributions?

Comment: Yes, not all of them, but some of them do have soft credits.